# cargar childs routes en el ngmodule

Tags: angular

quería eliminar los archivos de routing e importarlos directamente en los módulos pero solo me sirvió para el de `forRoot()` el de `forChild()` me sobrescribe las rutas de `forRoot()` alguien me podria decir porque o como lo podria hacer

**feactures.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component:ManualComponent,
    data:{"permi":"todo"}
  },
  {
    path: 'menu',
    component:MenuComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'settings',
    component:SettingsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: ...,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild(routes) // esta linea me esta sobrescribiendo las rutas
  ]
})
export class FeaturesModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    //loadChildren: () =>   import('./features/features.module').then(m => m.FeaturesModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),// importo los routes
    CoreModule,
    FeaturesModule,// importo el modulo de feactures
    SharedModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

comente el `loadChildren` en **app.module.ts** para ver si era este el problema, pero no es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario que vuelvas a importar el modulo de features. Ya lo estas haciendo en lazy loading. Al importarlo estas trayendo también todas sus rutas,  por eso se sobre escriben.

```
imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),// importo los routes
    CoreModule,
    FeaturesModule,// Eliminalo de aqui.
    SharedModule
  ],
```

```
{
    path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    //Esta es la importación. Si analizas bien la estructura lo entenderas. Se hace así
    //para cargar de forma peresoza (cuando se requiera el modulo a travez del path)
    loadChildren: () =>   import('./features/features.module').then(m => m.FeaturesModule)
  },
```